# DXA 2.0 : Display components in page in the sequence they are added

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

We have pages set up using different CTs in a particular order.

For example:

- component 1 - CT 1
- component 2 - CT 2
- component 3 - CT 1
- component 4 - CT 1
- component 5 - CT 3

When it loads the page, it groups all the CTs in a single group and then displays on the page. So instead of displaying it in sequence the components have been added in, it displays all components with CT 2 first, then CT 3 and then CT 1

This is obviously a problem because content authors want to display the components in the order that they are adding them in.

We are using `@Html.DxaEntities()` for our main region.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DXA groups CPs by *Region*.

That is: DXA CTs should have DXA metadata which specifies in which Region the CP should go.

If you want to prevent grouping of your CPs, you should ensure they all go in the same Region, by ensuring that their CTs specify the same Region (View) Name.

An issue has been reported earlier that the Region grouping behavior could be done differently, but this has not been implemented yet: 
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/26